# How to do a MySQL recursive query?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, geolocation, geocoding, recursive-query

I have the following recrusive query in postgres which given a particular GeoNames id (in this case 6429727) get its name and the name and id of each place containing it all the way up the hierarchy:

```
WITH RECURSIVE geonametree AS

 (SELECT geoname.geonameid AS id
       , geoname.name AS name
       , hierarchy.parentid AS parent
       , hierarchy.childid AS child
    FROM hierarchy
    JOIN geoname ON geoname.geonameid = hierarchy.childid 
   WHERE geoname.geonameid = 6429727

UNION ALL

 SELECT geoname.geonameid AS id
      , geoname.name AS name
      , hi.parentid AS parent
      , hi.childid AS child
   FROM hierarchy AS hi
   JOIN geoname ON geoname.geonameid = hi.parentid 
  INNER JOIN geonametree AS gt ON (hi.childid = gt.parent)
 )

SELECT id
     , name
     , parent
     , child
  FROM geonametree;
```

How can I achieve the same in MySQL - the documentation isnt very clear or I'm not understanding it very well.